# Python raspberry pi - how to treat RAM memory as a file

Tags: python, file, io, ram

on raspberry pi opencv python, I'm successfully capturing an image from a USB cam, then saving as 'image.png' then passing the filename to an smtp client that reads in the file and sends it as an attachement in an email. obviously this is bad for the sd card...

how do I treat an area of RAM as a file? that I can stream data to and from?..

I'm not at home now but if needed I can attach code of what I've tried so far.

cheers

Comment: It's not bad for the SD card - it just means you're using it. Can you elaborate on how you're creating the file? Depending on the libraries you are using - you might be able to save the data into a variable and skip the entire filesystem.

Comment: Thanks Shadow :) consider i'm basically doing this for a high number of frames from the video stream. but regardless, it's not an elegant solution and I rather do it on ram. so the file is created by cv2.imwrite('myimage.png', img) and then I don't have the code in front of me but something along the lines of server.attach('myimage.png') ... I think I have tried just going server.attach(img) and it complained img does not have a read attribute... so I was looking at bytesIO as that allows me to create a file like object that can handles such things as seek and read ... but no luck so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a ram drive using the following;

```
sudo mount ramfs <DIRECTORY> -t ramfs -o size=<SIZE>
```

An example that creates a 16 megabyte ram drive at `/ram`:

```
sudo mount ramfs /ram -t ramfs -o size=16M
```

If this is working for you, and you want to make sure this is automatically created every time you start your pi, you'll need to update your `/etc/fstab`.

---

Once you've done this, you won't need to make any architectural changes to your code. Just make sure your file operations are happening in this directory. Needless to say, anything you store here will magically disappear if you restart your pi for any reason.

Comment: unfortunately this didnt work for me, says it can't mount /data, there was no /data folder, so i created it and i still got the same message. then i tried to modify the fstab file and it has crashed my pi i cant ssh anymore need to reflash card... call me stubborn but i'm clearly not conversant in linux commands i much rather do this from within python... there must be a way to treat some area of ram as a file.(?)

Comment: Odd. It would have been interesting to see a transcript of what you tried exactly. But no - there isn't anything like that to my knowledge. Your best bet (as per my first comment) is to find a way to use StringIO/BytesIO.

Comment: i've finished flashing the card, this is what happens: sudo mount ramfs /ram -t ramfs -o size=16M
mount: mount point /ram does not exist    and then if i create ram... i.e. mkdir ram and try again i get the exact same message

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that situation... try rebooting? I suppose you could give tmpfs a whirl too (ram drive, but can use disk if you use too much ram)

Comment: so the solution was to mount a ram drive, though the commands where slightly different, I had to use  **mkdir ram
 mkfs -q /dev/ram1 1024  
 mount /dev/ram1 ram**   .... I did for a while persist in trying to create a ram file in python, there are several examples of how to save an image to a string stream but that yielded a fileno() not supported error, and from what I can find this is a bug...